# properties that a finite-dimensional vector spaces has but an infinite-dimensional one doesn't.

Tags: vector-spaces

i am mostly translating my question (from french) so sorry for the rough english, but i would like to know some examples of properties that a  finite-dimensional vector space has but an infinite-dimensional vector space doesn't.

Comment: A finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is always isomorphic to its dual space, which is not true for infinite dimensional vector spaces

Comment: Separability, Completeness, Heine-Borel, All linear operators between finite-dimensional normed spaces are bounded, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: @user That's more like for topological vector spaces, and the OP seems to want something only from linear algebra, without topology...

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/bdj27x/linear_algebra_theorems_that_dont_generalize_to/ has lots of examples

Comment: if $V$ is finite dimensional, then a linear map with a one sided inverse from $V$ to itself must be invertible, but this is false for infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520705)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example.  If $V$ is a vector space and $f:V\rightarrow V$ is linear and injective, it is a priori surjective if $V$ is finite dimensional. This fails in the infinite dimensional case.   Similarly, if $f$ is surjective, it must also be injective if $V$ is finite dimensional. This fails in the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: Examples, please?

Comment: Look at the vector space of sequences of real numbers.